# Exit from while loop which started inside a async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, while-loop

How to break the while loop which inside an async method. Please refer below code

I have tried many ways but none of them worked for me

```
async void TotalTimer(string time)
{
    while (true)
    {
        TimeSpan timesp = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(time);
        TotalTime = timesp.Hours + " : " + timesp.Minutes + " : " + timesp.Seconds;
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to stop and exit from the loop

---

Updated code:

```
async Task TotalTimer(CancellationToken token)
{
    var intime = await App.Database.GetRecentIn();
    InTime = DateTime.Parse(intime.datetime).ToString("hh:mm tt");


    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        TimeSpan timesp = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(intime.datetime);
        TotalTime = timesp.Hours + " : " + timesp.Minutes + " : " + timesp.Seconds;
        Console.WriteLine(TotalTime); // to see it's working
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void StatCounting()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _= TotalTimer(cts.Token);
}

void StopCounting()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.Cancel();
   _= TotalTimer(cts.Token);

    _=Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can because everything inside Task.Run is an annonymous function. If you had that code inside it's own function and then call that instead of an annonymous one, you would probably see why it doesn't work.

Comment: When would your exit condition of `string.IsNullOrEmpty(time)` ever be true here? I see nothing changing the value of `time`, and if it wasn't populated to start with your `DateTime.Parse(time)` call would throw

Comment: I tried that and updated the code to that method. But not working. after breaking TotalTime getting update

Comment: @steve16351 it will pass from another method

Comment: @Argon, the scope of `time` here doesn't allow another method to update it outside of what you've shown.

Comment: @steve16351 sorry I didn't get what you ask.

Comment: @Argon, you think you're changing `time`, but you aren't, that's where the problem lies.

Comment: Using `async void` is probably the wrong choice here (it ususally is).

Comment: @HenkHolterman I have updated code. Please take a look.

Comment: You create 2 TotalTimer's , the second with a pre-canceled token. The first one will keep on ticking. You also create 2 TokenSources. One cannot stop the other.

Comment: Can you give me a way to do this without creating two?  :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `CancellationToken` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private string TotalTime;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().Run();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            TotalTimer("00:00:00", cts.Token);

            Console.ReadLine(); // waits for you to press 'Enter' to stop TotalTimer execution.
            cts.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'Enter' to exit the program.");
            Console.ReadLine();  // waits for you to press 'Enter' to exit the program. See, TotalTimer stopped.
        }

        // your original method modified
        async void TotalTimer(string time, CancellationToken token)
        {
            while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                TimeSpan timesp = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(time);
                TotalTime = timesp.Hours + " : " + timesp.Minutes + " : " + timesp.Seconds;
                Console.WriteLine(TotalTime); // to see it's working
                await Task.Delay(5000, token);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

@Henk Holterman, according to edits history `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time))` looks like an attempt to break the loop from outside. But it's pointless for two reasons:

- strings are immutable
- if `time` is null or empty `DateTime.Parse(time)` (it was in the **original** post) throws before the check

Adding the token to `Task.Delay` is a good point. Doing so saves resources, though makes no difference to observable behaviour.

**Update2**

@Argon, the code is independent to `wpf`, `winforms`, `console` or whatever. See minimal `wpf` example bellow. I checked it's working. If something does not work with you concrete code, you maybe hiding some details from us.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private string TotalTime;
        private CancellationTokenSource cts;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            TotalTimer("00:00:00", cts.Token);
        }

        async void TotalTimer(string time, CancellationToken token)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    TimeSpan timesp = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(time);
                    TotalTime = timesp.Hours + " : " + timesp.Minutes + " : " + timesp.Seconds;
                    label1.Content = TotalTime;
                    await Task.Delay(5000, token);
                }
            }
            catch(OperationCanceledException)
            {
                label1.Content = "Canceled";
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have a cancelToken you might as well pass it to Task.Delay() as well.

Comment: I do not understand the vote down, but I suspect your code is what the op is looking for. That is, cancelling a running operation.

Comment: You made up an MCVE around the question but you lost the `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(time))` logic. Which is probably the source of the confusion.

Comment: As @HenkHolterman says, I would indeed add an explanation why the ops code is not working.

Comment: It's working on console app. but in WPF its keep running

Comment: WPF would have been a very important tag to add to the question.

Comment: Instead of checking explicitly for `token.IsCancellationRequested`, I would prefer a `while (true)` with a call to [`token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested) at the start of the loop. Catching the `OperationCanceledException` is the default way of handling a cancellation event.

Comment: Alex, Henk HolterMan, Silvermind Thanks for the guidance. 

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias, why not, it's a way too.

Comment: Great improvement on the answer. I would also suggest not to catch `TaskCancelledException`, but `OperationCancelledException`, because `TaskCancelledException` derives from it so you would catch that, but `CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancelled`, throws the said one.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `break` in an `async` method is perfectly fine.

This works fine:

```
async void Main()
{
    await TotalTimer();
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}

async Task TotalTimer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        if (true)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It waits a second and then write `Done.` to the console.

Your code just doesn't change `time` so it's never hitting the `break`.

Other than that your `async` method should return a `Task` rather than a `void`.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have updated my code, please review it

Comment: @Argon - Also, please don't edit your question so that it makes existing answers look wrong. Always append updates to the edit of the question unless you are editing a mistake in your question.

Comment: @Argon - Finally, your update code is just plain wrong now. You should only create one `new CancellationTokenSource()` and only call `TotalTimer` once.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I will do in next time. 

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for your effort guys. I have figure out a way to stop the loop. I have defined boolean and checked it within the while loop to break the loop. Its most likely @Enigmativitys answer.

```
bool hasToStop = false;
while (true)
            {
                TimeSpan timesp = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(intime.datetime);
                TotalTime = timesp.Hours + " : " + timesp.Minutes + " : " + timesp.Seconds;
                Console.WriteLine(TotalTime); // to see it's working
                await Task.Delay(1000);

                if (hasToStop)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Stoped");
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you update the variable `hasToStop` from a different thread, then your code is unsafe. Your loop could never end because the worker thread may see forever a cached value of the variable. In that case you should either declare the variable as [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile), or `lock` everytime you use it. Even better use the dedicated struct provided be the .NET Framework for exactly this reason: [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken).

Comment: This is a bad idea to do from another thread. The `token.IsCancellationRequested` is the right approach.